# selecting multiple answers for a single cell from a drop down source

Tags: google-apps-script

This is what i want to do:
https://spreadsheetpoint.com/multiple-selection-drop-down-google-sheets/
But every step i follow, it wont happen.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WPB-gHSXzjJw9p8s00HmmBTzGePtP4W_YO-LJXNSSX0/edit#gid=1549684096
Here is the document. I want to be able to select multiple colleges at once to show that a student got into more than one.

Please help!

I am using the code in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry;")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    if (e.value) {
      let s = e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
      if(s && s.length > 0) {
        e.source.toast(s)
        e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(s + '\n' + e.value);
      } else {
        e.source.toast('B');
        e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(e.value);
      }
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

[image]